How much does having competing offers benefit a job search?
Due to personal reasons I have a strong preference to stay in a certain geographic region, and I will apply to all tenure track positions in this region. I would probably prefer to leave academia than take a tenure track job outside this region.
My profile is strong enough I'm confident I would be able to get a R1 tenure track job if I apply broadly, but not strong enough to be confident I will be able to get a job in the region of interest.
I'm wondering whether I should still apply broadly, even for jobs I think I would have a low (but nonzero) chance of taking.
In particular, I have heard:

having one offer may increase the chances of getting another offer
if you have upcoming interviews, you may be able to negotiate a longer time-frame to make a decision on an offer (and my ability to do this would be limited if I only applied to a few local schools)

This makes me think that it would be beneficial to apply broadly and use any potential offers as leverage to get a job I am more interested in. But I'm not sure if this is worth the effort it takes to put together a good application.

Wow, the answers here are so much different from what I would expect from the same question on Workplace. I'll just chime in as a comment. Announcing that you already have another offer, early in the process, can be seen as a negative sign. Think about it. You're basically saying that the later companies weren't high choices and that there is a high chance that their time and resources pursuing you. As Bryan mentioned, having another offer is good for negotiating, and for that, you don't mention the other offer until you are at phase where you wish to apply pressure.

I personally think it's unethical to apply for jobs that you would not take in any circumstance. That type of game-playing is wasting real people's time.
I can't imagine it would ever help you get an offer to have an existing offer. There is certainly correlation in that having an offer means there's something in your application to justify giving you an offer and committees tend to be looking for similar things.
Competing offers help you in the negotiating after you have an offer, though that doesn't mean whoever you're negotiating with necessarily has anything to give, and if you're not actually willing to take the other offer you might end up negotiating yourself into looking like a conniving idiot when you first say you won't take the position unless they match some other offer and then come back with your tail between your legs when they say "sorry we'll have to go with our next choice then".

I agree with most of your answer but I'm not sure about this: I can't imagine it would ever help you get an offer to have an existing offer. It can make you seem more desirable, and put some time pressure on a decision if said school has reason to believe you'd accept over the other offer.  I've seen a couple instances where I think it helped, though I can't be sure whether an offer wouldn't have been made anyway.

This makes sense. I'm not planning on applying anywhere I definitely wouldn't go. But it's a bit hard to calibrate how much effort to put into places I'm not currently super excited about right now but might (or might not) be after a visit. I figured soft factors like I'm asking about might have some impact on the exact balance.

+1 for I personally think it's unethical to apply for jobs that you would not take in any circumstance. That type of game-playing is wasting real people's time.

@Kimball I can see some influence on more discretionary hires for the reasons you give, but faculty searches are normally pretty formalized and not made on a whim. Dan's answer mentions that even if it's a possibility it's at least as likely to go the other way if they'd rather make an offer to someone likely to accept (especially if they're on a time crunch or are worried they'd lose their second choice, too, especially if they grade out similarly).

I don't see a good reason to heap ethical shame upon an OP who is already dealing with the stress of a job search. Lying on a job application is unethical. Bribing a hiring manager is unethical. But seeking out competing offers in order to signal your desirability to a prospective employer is just how the job market works. The notion of "jobs you would not take in any circumstance" is a strawman: You never have complete information about any position (and whether or not you would take it) until you apply and interview.

@Max I'm not "heaping ethical shame", I'm saying it's unethical to waste people's time this way: time of the search committee, time of the other applicants. Search committee members are more or less volunteers, it's a service role that doesn't directly benefit them (there are indirect benefits of picking your colleagues and influencing the field, of course). No strawman here, no, you don't have complete information and aren't required to take a job that is offered, but you shouldn't apply if you already know you won't take it. That's not much of a heap.

"I personally think it's unethical"—this might be a generational thing, but that is quite charged language where I come from. And the idea that search committees are "volunteers" is simply irrelevant. As soon as you "volunteer" for a search committee (which you and I both know is not really optional), reading applications becomes part of your job.

In fact, I'm not certain that "wasting someone's time" is an ethical transgression to begin with. Submitting a paper to a top tier journal, where you are basically certain you won't get published, is arguably "wasting" the editor's time, and might be inadvisable if you are in a rush to publish—but is that unethical?

The strawman is the idea that these are jobs the OP "would not take under any circumstance." OP didn't say that. OP said they have a "strong preference" to remain in this region. Getting these kinds of details right is critical if you are going to call someone "unethical," a term that connotes fraud and abuse, not normal job seeking behavior.

@Max what Bryan said was that it’s unethical to apply for jobs you would not take under any circumstance. You could argue it doesn’t answer OP’s exact question, but I think it’s both a helpful and correct statement. Moreover, OP’s question is worded confusingly and seems to at least implicitly be asking whether it’s ethical to game the hiring process by applying to jobs you are uninterested in in order to gain an advantage w.r.t. other applications, and use the fact that there is a “low but nonzero probability” you would take that job to rationalize that said behavior is in fact ethical.

… so all things considered, I think your criticism of @Bryan’s answer is a bit misguided. It’s a good and helpful answer.

@Max As Dan writes, I'm setting a boundary for what is ethical. That doesn't mean things right up to the boundary on one side are perfect and on the other side of the boundary is Evil. Murder is unethical besides special exceptions; swiping your coworker's paperclips for work purposes without intention of replacing them or informing them is unethical. I'm not equating these in severity, and it doesn't mean I'm calling OP out: it's helpful to know where you are in regards to ethics even if you're on the "okay" side because as you approach the gray area different people will see it differently.

Not always true. In Germany, as a professor, you cannot be promoted or vye for higher salary unless you get an offer elsewhere. So, it very much depends. I didn't downvote, as the answer applies to some areas, but I did not upvote either, as the answer does not apply to some areas.

@CaptainEmacs I would not consider a promotion or higher salary to be a job search in the sense that OP is asking about; higher salary would be included in the statement opening the third paragraph: "Competing offers help you in the negotiating after you have an offer".


having one offer may increase the chances of getting another offer

This is not entirely inconceivable, but it’s also not entirely inconceivable that another job offer might actually deter some departments (particularly departments that are less highly ranked than the department that made you an offer) from making you an offer. Both of those scenarios are in any case fairly unlikely. Serious departments do not usually give much weight to this type of information before making an offer. (Source of my knowledge: former math department chair in the US.)
By contrast, as @BryanKrause said, having multiple offers can very possibly help you negotiate good terms after you have already received an offer.
As far as ethics is concerned, I also agree with @BryanKrause that applying to jobs you are absolutely not interested in is unethical. But beyond ethics, and beyond the fact that it wouldn’t really produce the effect you’re intending, I think it’s a bad idea for multiple reasons having to do with what might happen in various situations where things don’t quite go according to your plan. You risk not just upsetting other people, but possibly upsetting yourself, and setting yourself up for all sorts of dilemmas where you have to weigh competing desires (geography versus career) of yourself and/or family members, in a situation where you are essentially declaring in advance that you specifically want to avoid these types of dilemmas.
To summarize, if you think you might accept a job offer outside of your geographical target zone, then it’s reasonable to apply for such jobs. But if you have already made a decision that you wouldn’t take such a job under any circumstance, you are courting all sorts of unpleasant unintended consequences, and I think your plan is highly inadvisable. (Of course, it’s often the case with unethical behaviors that they invite negative consequences, but somehow in the current situation some of those consequences seem not directly related to the unethical nature of the behavior, so I thought it’s worth pointing out.)
Good luck with your job search in any case.

Thanks for the response. I guess I need to think more about what I want (although I've been trying to do this for the last half decade to little success...). I'm not committed to staying put, I've just enjoyed living here more than anywhere else I've been. I sort of only have one shot at applications, but also I don't want to waste my/committees time on things that won't benefit anyone.

Something else to consider is that interviewing and getting job offers is a skill, which is hard to practice. If you do poorly in a job interview, you can generally reflect on your performance, identify areas of improvement, rehearse better for next time etc. Neither of those helps you if the interview was for the one job you really wanted. So from that angle, applying to other jobs is worthwhile even if just for the interviewing practice (provided you take the interview process seriously).
Another comment suggests that applying for jobs you would never take is wasting people's time and thus unethical, and I don't really disagree. Equally, never is a very long time. You might really like your prospective colleagues, or the campus, or something else about an offer, or simply not get any better offers at all, academia or not. So perhaps it's more that you are unlikely to take these jobs, unless somehow you are surprised by the circumstances. And the only way to find out is to apply, and take the process seriously.

In my own experience, going straight from undergrad in Physics & Computer Science to Software Engineering for government contracts to Software Engineering in the FinTech space; you should be interviewing for companies and positions second on your list before interviewing with those first on your list. Across that decade of experience, I've worked at over five companies, jumping from job to job if the offer was better. Some would say this is morally questionable, but I disagree. Industry, academia, and government are different in ways, but have important similarities. They all have a budget and they all have tactics for exploiting us. It's important to arm yourself in the same way they do. Do you think they're only interviewing a single candidate? Of course not. Why would you exclude yourself from interviewing everywhere you could? Do not fall for the idea that it's morally correct to save yourself for a single employer.
Let's run the scenario: you interview at your second, third, or fourth choice. If the interviews go poorly, good, you got some practice before the real thing. If the interviews go well, good, you might get an offer before your first choice and you can use that as leverage when negotiating for the first choice position, assuming you get to the negotiating table. Finally, you interview at your first choice, and you're armed with the practice rounds you just performed in the weeks prior. This is not "stealing" resources from other companies. You are now simply playing the exact same game as them.
